# Exact Differential Equation Constant Implicit Form Different Answers Rearranged

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My original DE is: $$(3x^2-y^2)dy - 2xydx = 0$$
If I find an integrating factor and modify this original equation with the integrating factor, I end up with the solution in implicit form: $$y^{-1}-x^2y^{-3}=C$$
If I modify this DE to: $$2xydx + (y^2-3x^2)dy = 0$$
My implicit solution becomes:
$$x^2y^{-3}-y^{-1}=C$$
So are these two solutions equivalent?

Comment: they are different equations. you flipped the sign on both $2xydx$ and $(3x^2-y^2)dy$ but you also reversed the order of expressions in the parenthesis. it should be $2xydx-(3x^2-y^2)dy=0$

Comment: @benji I meant to make the sign after dx a '+'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have the same solutions. Just note that for the second solution you should give the constant a different name say $C_1$ then you will have

> $$ x^2y^{-3}-y^{-1}=C_1 \implies  y^{-1}-x^2y^{-3}= -C_1 = C.  $$

which is your first solution.

Comment: How do you know which solution is correct? Should I put the solution in what it should be for the given solution?

Comment: @Norm: As I said for the second solution you should give a different name to the constant and the relation between the two constants as you see from my answer is $C=-C_1$. Have you seen what I did with your second solution. I just multiplied it by $-1$ and I replaced $-C_1$ by $C$ which is the first solution.

Comment: @Norm: I said in my answer "you should have the same solutions". Both of your solution are correct except you should give a different name to the arbitrary constant in your second solution.

Comment: I mean is the first one correct because that is what is given?